# How to detect an interval between consecutive rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

Consider the following rows:

```
Id   RecordedOn         
1    9/3/19 11:15:00    
2    9/3/19 11:15:01    
3    9/3/19 11:15:02    
4    9/3/19 11:18:55    
5    9/3/19 11:18:01
```

As you can see, there are typically records every second, but from row 3 to row 4, there is a gap.

How do I find gaps like these?  Preferably I'd like the starting and ending row of the gap, so `3, 4` in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want both the before and after rows, use `lag()` and `lead()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(recordedon) over (order by recordedon) as prev_ro,
             lead(recordedon) over (order by recordedon) as next_ro
      from t
     ) t
where prev_ro < dateadd(second, -1, recordedon) or
      next_ro > dateadd(second, 1, recordedon);
```

Answer (score 1):

[**SQL DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/21ee79/4)

```
SELECT *,  DATEDIFF(second, previous, [RecordedOn]) as diff
FROM ( 
  SELECT [Id], [RecordedOn], LAG([RecordedOn]) OVER (ORDER BY [RecordedOn]) previous
  FROM t
) t
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| Id |           RecordedOn |             previous |   diff |
|----|----------------------|----------------------|--------|
|  1 | 2019-09-03T11:15:00Z |               (null) | (null) |
|  2 | 2019-09-03T11:15:01Z | 2019-09-03T11:15:00Z |      1 |
|  3 | 2019-09-03T11:15:02Z | 2019-09-03T11:15:01Z |      1 |
|  5 | 2019-09-03T11:18:01Z | 2019-09-03T11:15:02Z |    179 |
|  4 | 2019-09-03T11:18:55Z | 2019-09-03T11:18:01Z |     54 |
```

You can also use LAG() to get previous `id` if need it.

Answer (score 1):

You could self-join the table with a `LEFT JOIN` anti-pattern to exhibit records for which no record exist 1 second later, like:

```
SELECT t.id
FROM mytable t
LEFT JOIN mytable t1 ON t1.RecordedOn = DATEADD(second, 1, t.RecordedOn)
WHERE t1.id IS NULL
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bcfb45d4c16af0a04820714893de3985)**:

```
| id |
| -: |
|  3 |
|  4 |
|  5 |
```